# Vertically center content between header and footer

Tags: css, html, screen-size

I wonder if any one can help me. I have a website with a header, footer and content containers. Now I wish to vertically centre the content between the header and footer containers instead of the page. Does anybody have any ideas how to achieve this???

Comment: code please... or a fiddle :)

Answer (score 0):

try the below css

```
        <div >header</div>
        <div class="container">
               <p>This small paragraph...</p>
        </div>
        <div >footer</div>
```

CSS:

```
           div.container {
                min-height: 10em;
                display: table-cell;
                vertical-align: middle ;}
```

Answer (score 0):

try the below css

```
        <div class="wrapper">
           <div >header</div>
           <div class="container">
               <p>This small paragraph...</p>
           </div>
           <div >footer</div>
       </div>
```

CSS:

```
        .wrapper{ display: table; }

        div.container {
            min-height: 10em;
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle ;
        }
```

Try this i just added wrapper with display:table style.

table-cell property will work only with a wrapper having display:table property